# Gnome failure after update

Tags: 11.04, gdm, updates

I originally asked this question over the Ubuntu forums, but I'm not really sure where the best place to get help is. Anyway...

I've had Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my desktop since it's release. Up until an hour ago, it was working fine. I clicked on an update from the update manager, now booting into a graphical mode is completely broken, (the start-up load hangs at 'Check Battery State ... [0k]'). I restarted my computer, and booted into safe mode, and launched the terminal. This all works fine. I then typed :

```
sudo gdm start
```

into the command prompt, hoping that I would be able to start things manually. Instead, it spat out this:

```
gdm-binary[230]: WARNING: Unable to load file '/etc/gdm/custom.conf'. No such file or directory.
gdm-binary[230]: WARNING: Unable to find users : no seat-id found.
gdm-binary[230]: WARNING: Gdm Display: display lasted 0.070467 seconds
```

The last line was printed about 8 times, with slightly different times, before it gave up and failed. Some information which might help, I have Gnome 2, Unity and KDE (not sure which version), installed. My graphics card is the GTX 275, and I have driver the Nvidia driver 275.21. So yeah, I think the update has gone and moved custom.conf somewhere, but I have no idea on how to fix it. I have a graphics programming assignment due on Friday and I would be eternally grateful if I could get this fixed well before then. Thanks.

Comment: try to run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm`

Comment: I gave that a go, but it still produced the same error.

Comment: then check whether the file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` exists. if not, you should try to create one. i'll post the main contents in a bit..

Comment: Thanks Pavlos. Gdm is right, the file doesn't exist, and there are no temp or hidden files in the directory that it might be related to.

Comment: Can you run `gdmsetup`? Are there any files in the `/etc/gdm/` folder or is it empty?

Comment: No, Gdmsetup is gui based, so I just get an error telling me it can't create a window.

Comment: @DarcyRayner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1151/discussion-between-pavlos-g-and-darcy-rayner)

Comment: glad to hear that you solved it ;-)

Comment: @Pavlos Please post the solution as an answer, not in the question, that way we can mark it answered.

Comment: @Jorge Wouldn't it be better for Darcy to do that on his own? He found the answer after all (just asking..)

Comment: Sure, whichever works out best. Just don't forget to removed that [Solved] stuff when he's done.

Comment: Just added my answer, I'll tick it when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I managed to solve this issue. The trouble was that I wasn't using the Ubuntu packaged graphics driver, so after a kernel update the kernel was expecting a particular graphics driver, but was actually linked against a newer version. Re-installing the driver seems to have fixed the problem temporarily, but it might re-occur as soon as I do another kernel update.